# How to format numbers in DAX, based on a condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have `var _sales` and I would like to format it based on its decimal numbers.

Expected Answer:

```
If the number is `15.506,514 Million` = `15 M` 
`15.606,514 Million` = `16 M`
```

How to get around the code below. many thanks in advance.

```
var _result =
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    ABS( _sales ) >= 1000000, FORMAT( _sales, "$#,##0,,M"),
    ABS( _sales ) >= 1000, FORMAT( _sales, "$#,##0,k"),
    FORMAT( _sales, "$#,##0" )
)
RETURN _result
```

Comment: Your questions isn't clear. What is your expected result?

Comment: sorry for the late respond. I just modified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. You may need to switch the , and . for your regional settings.

Either

FORMAT( _sales, "0,,.M" )

or

FORMAT( _sales, "0..,M" )